# using ajax to insert into database without refreshing page- laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

i have a form which i insert the data into dsatabase usind laravel request.
it works properly but i want to use ahax to insert it into the database without page refresh. i have no idea of how to go about it. the form is below

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{url('Others/Doctor/Diagnosis/patient_diagnosis')}}">

                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="appointment_id" value="{{ $apt->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="doctor_id" value="{{ $apt->doctor_id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{ $apt->patient_id }}">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('complaints') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Complaints</label>
                               {{--<input type="text" name="complaints" id="complaints" class="form-control">--}}
                                <textarea name="complaints" id="complaints" class="form-control" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
                                @if ($errors->has('complaints'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('complaints') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Case Study</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Then my controller is as below

```
  public function postCaseStudy(Request $request){

    //$request=Input::all();
    //dd($request);
    $this->validate($request,[
        'complaints' => 'required'
    ]);

    $appointment_id = $request[trim('appointment_id')];
    $patient_id = $request[trim('patient_id')];
    $doctor_id = $request[trim('doctor_id')];
    $complaints = $request[trim('complaints')];

    //dd($patient_id);
    $PatientCase = new PatientCase();
    $PatientCase->appointment_id = $appointment_id;
    $PatientCase->patient_id = $patient_id;
    $PatientCase->doctor_id = $doctor_id;
    $PatientCase->complaints = $complaints;

    $PatientCase->save();

    return Redirect::to('Others/Doctor/Diagnosis/patient_diagnosis/'.$patient_id);

}
```

it works but i want to use ajax so the page won't refresh

Answer (score 0):

Give a id to form e.g id="form". Add jquery in your script

```
<script>
     $(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                        url: $('#form').attr('action');,
                        type:'POST',
                        data:$('#form').serialize(),
                        success:function(result){
                           //Do something with return data

                        }

                });
            });
        });
</script>
```